# Discord.js/MongoDB - cooldown command

Tags: mongodb, discord.js

I am creating my discord bot and I would like to create a cooldown with my commands using mongoDB, when I restart the bot, the cooldowns of the commands will reset. Do you know if it's possible, if there is a property or other in order to create my cooldown work with my database, and it doesn't reset even when i'm restarting the bot ?

thank's !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to accomplish this is to save a timestamp to the database, probably using the command name as the key, whenever the user runs the command successfully. Then, you can compare the timestamp in the database to the current timestamp, and check if the time since the last run is greater than the cooldown time.